# Easiest method to Trigger Azure DevOps pipeline (CI) from Bitbucket?

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, continuous-integration, bitbucket, pull-request

we have all our pipelines on Azure DevOps:
[image]

...but we are using a Repo from another team and it is on **Bitbucket Server** (company owned). We have our own branch there on the bitbucket repo we use, and I would like to be able to merge PRs to this bitbucket repo and have it "trigger" the Azure (build) pipeline. I am currently just running it manually but it is very tedious. Also, this is on a Bitbucket Server that my company owns (not the regular bitbucket cloud (public) so we have our own custom domain name i.e. `www.bitbucket.MY-COMPANY-NAME.com`). I tried using the built-in feature on Azure devops (CI) build pipeline to *link* to the bitbucket repo to trigger "Scheduled" builds at 12AM at night but it always fails for this message:

```
An exception occurred while polling the repository. Error:
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException: No references received in
 the response from https://bitbucket.MY-COMPANY-NAME.com/scm/some-repo/some-repo.git/info/refs?
service=git-upload-pack. Status: 502, Reason: Bad Gateway at
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.ReadRefs(IVssRequestContext
 requestContext, HttpResponseMessage response) in
 D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitConnector.cs:line 318 at
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(IVssRequestContext
 requestContext, ExternalConnection connection, Int32 timeoutSeconds, Boolean useAnonymousAccess) in
 D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitConnector.cs:line 125 at
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetMatchingBranchRefs(IVssRequestCont
ext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, IList`1 branchFilters) in
 D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitSourceProvider.cs:line 463 at
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceVersionsToBuild(IVssRequestC
ontext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, List`1 branchFilters, Boolean batchChanges, String
 previousVersionEvaluated, Dictionary`2& ciData, String& lastVersionEvaluated) in
 D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitSourceProvider.cs:line 369 at
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.BuildPollingJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext
 requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage) in
 D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\BuildPollingJobExtension.cs:line 98.

No logs available for this run
```

Comment: Does your bitbucket server this option https://devcenter.bitrise.io/img/webhooks/bitbucket_add_webhooks.png ?

Comment: Hi there, please check whether the document in my answer can help you. Could you please tell me that whether your bitbucket server is reachable from Azure DevOps?

Comment: Are you using service connection to connnect to your Bitbucket Server and run the pipeline on self-hosted agents?

Comment: @ennth Hi there, is there any updates for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's document [Build on-premises Bitbucket repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/on-premises-bitbucket?view=azure-devops):

> If your on-premises server is reachable from the servers that run
> Azure Pipelines service, then:
>
> - you can set up classic build and configure CI triggers
>
> **If your on-premises server is not reachable from the servers that run Azure Pipelines service, then:**
>
> - you can set up classic build pipelines and start manual builds
> - you cannot configure CI triggers
>
> YAML pipelines do not work with on-premises Bitbucket repositories.
>
> **PR triggers are not available with on-premises Bitbucket repositories.**

And here is [a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/on-premises-bitbucket?view=azure-devops#i-pushed-a-change-to-my-server-but-the-pipeline-is-not-being-triggered) that provides some troubleshooting advices about failing triggers:

> - Is your Bitbucket server accessible from Azure Pipelines? Azure    Pipelines periodically polls Bitbucket server for changes. If the
>   Bitbucket server is behind a firewall, this traffic may not reach
>   your server. See Azure DevOps IP Addresses and verify that you have
>   granted exceptions to all the required IP addresses. These IP
>   addresses may have changed since you have originally set up the
>   exception rules. You can only start manual runs if you used an
>   external Git connection and if your server is not accessible from
>   Azure Pipelines.
> - Is your pipeline paused or disabled? Open the editor for the    pipeline, and then select Settings to check. If your pipeline is
>   paused or disabled, then triggers do not work.
> - Have you excluded the branches or paths to which you pushed your    changes? Test by pushing a change to an included path in an included
>   branch. Note that paths in triggers are case-sensitive. Make sure
>   that you use the same case as those of real folders when specifying
>   the paths in triggers.